# systemd -- permanently add boot loader options (PopOs)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, systemd

So I've got PopOS 20.04 installed and it runs pretty well...
The only issue I'm encountering is with suspend. This needs to be set to `deep` instead of `s2idle`

This can be done, for the current session, with this command:

```bsh
sudo su
echo deep > /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

That works....
But it gets reset

So I'm wondering, how can I make this change permanent ?
Tried appending the option `mem_sleep_default=deep` in `/boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-current.conf`, as I used to do in GRUB when on vanilla Ubuntu, but this file gets reset with every kernel update.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

dGo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pop!_OS manages boot entries using [kernelstub](https://github.com/pop-os/kernelstub). Its configuration is stored in a JSON file at `/etc/kernelstub/configuration`. You can add boot options there under `default` → `kernel_options`.

See the other answer for information on how to edit this file using the `kernelstub` command. Don't forget to upvote that answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: cheers ! Looks like that is what I was looking for

Comment: Tried it not working for me! any other way to do this? Here is my problem, https://superuser.com/questions/1682713/pop-os-kernel-parameters-setting-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest trying the kernel boot option "acpi_osi=" in the place of the option you suggested?

This will correct a lot of issues with sleep and hibernate.

But to answer your question as you asked.

It is recommended to test the parameter on this setup before adding it, one would suggest you hold the space bar when powering up the system to catch the boot menu, then hit the "e" key to edit the line command line and test your boot option before saving it.

kernelstub works as following

To add a boot use -a "options" yours would be as follows

```
kernelstub -a "mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

To delete a boot option use -d "options" yours would be as follows

```
kernelstub -d "mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

and

```
# kernelstub -p
kernelstub.Config    : INFO     Looking for configuration...
kernelstub           : INFO     System information: 

    OS:..................Pop!_OS 22.04
    Root partition:....../dev/dm-1
    Root FS UUID:........f3b6a3b7-32e7-4f9c-9b8d-1952d5d8e0f3
    ESP Path:............/boot/efi
    ESP Partition:......./dev/nvme0n1p1
    ESP Partition #:.....1
    NVRAM entry #:.......-1
    Boot Variable #:.....0000
    Kernel Boot Options:.quiet systemd.show_status=false splash loglevel=0 acpi_osi=
    Kernel Image Path:.../boot/vmlinuz-6.2.6-76060206-generic
    Initrd Image Path:.../boot/initrd.img-6.2.6-76060206-generic
    Force-overwrite:.....False

kernelstub           : INFO     Configuration details: 

   ESP Location:................../boot/efi
   Management Mode:...............True
   Install Loader configuration:..True
   Configuration version:.........3
```