# Pop!_OS : setting kernel parameters (boot loader options) permanently is not working

Tags: graphics-card, grub, kernel, qemu, pop-os

Was experimenting GPU passthrough with QEMU (following the steps given [here](https://mathiashueber.com/windows-virtual-machine-gpu-passthrough-ubuntu/)) on Pop!_OS and in the process I added kernel parameters.
Now I want to remove the `intel_iommu=on kvm.ignore_msrs=1 vfio-pci.ids=8086:3e9b` to regain locked VGA card. However altering parameters with popos seems not working for me. I am not an advanced user so I am sure I might be missing something here.

I tried (1) kernelstub, (2) updating grub and (3) modifying loader.conf (4) changing configuration (as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1583591/systemd-permanently-add-boot-loader-options-popos)), but no luck. You can find in the screenshot that, kernelstub is reporting only `quiet splash` being the active kernel parameters, however `cmdline` shows (otherwise) currently effective options.

Wondering how to alter the kernel parameters permanently so that VGA card to be returned to the host system. I had similar problem with Ubuntu, changing /etc/default/grub file and updating it easily solved it.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question but I want to rule this out: are you rebooting after making changes? What's in your `/boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-current.conf`?

Comment: Yes, I am restarting the machine every time when I make changes. and here .conf file contents.


`title Pop!_OS
linux /EFI/Pop_OS-328fbd3d-0fb9-445f-9dc3-99c298e6e94d/vmlinuz.efi
initrd /EFI/Pop_OS-328fbd3d-0fb9-445f-9dc3-99c298e6e94d/initrd.img
options root=UUID=328fbd3d-0fb9-445f-9dc3-99c298e6e94d ro quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false splash`

Comment: So the parts you wanted gone are gone from your bootloader config. Maybe you're not booting with systemd-boot (which kernelstub configures)? Is that system configured to boot in UEFI mode of CSM mode (aka BIOS aka legacy)?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help
The following will probably delete the kernel boot option you mentioned

```
kernelstub -d "intel_iommu=on kvm.ignore_msrs=1 vfio-pci.ids=8086:3e9b"
```

The following will add the kernel option you wanted.

```
kernelstub -a "intel_iommu=on kvm.ignore_msrs=1 vfio-pci.ids=8086:3e9b"
```

If you power off your system and then power it back on and hold space, then press "e" once you see the Bootloader option that interests you, you can edit the command line to see what your boot options are and change them for that boot cycle.

Comment: This proposal resolved the same issue for me on PopOs 22.04, I give the link to the official documentation https://support.system76.com/articles/kernelstub/